# Integrated terminal in visual studio

Tags: django, visual-studio, terminal, integrated

I am working on Visual Studio for a Django project
But I can't be able to open integrated terminal
What should I do?
I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: Visual Studio IDE 2019 community/professional or Visual Studio code editor?

Comment: I am not sure what happened, but I have been unable to find any news regarding the Visual Studio 2019 Integrated Terminal. All I know is that it was postponed from version 16.4 to be released in 16.5, but since that version has come out, it still doesn't seem available.

Comment: @k33da_lets_debug community